# Is there a way to enable avx2 intruction set without auto-vectorization by LLVM

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization, hpc

Recently I met a problem that my avx2 optimized program may crash on old machines like 2010 mac, which does not support avx2 intruction set. At the same time, I can ensure that all my avx2 code is surrounded by dynamically detection of instruction, which will not be run on an avx2-free machine.
So i digged into this problem and found that the crash is caused by auto-vectorization conducted by llvm itself. I tried -fno-vectorize and -fno-slp-vectorize but found that once -mavx2 is set, the program will be auto vectorized.
Is there a way to disable auto-vectorization in llvm with -mavx2 set? Because without -mavx2, my handwritten avx2 code may not be compiled successfully.

Comment: Did you try to self-defense & autodetect the AVX2 presence during the code runtime, before branching into AVX2?

Comment: Can you put the AVX2 code in a separate compilation unit?

Comment: yep，my handwritten avx2 is surrounded by autodetect condition.

Comment: i wrote some inline assemably code, which mixed with normal c/c++ code, i have to used -mavx2 to compile them. The normal c/c++ code, which is necessary in any condition, will be auto-vectorized, may still cause crash on some old machines

Comment: avx2 inline assemably does not need -mavx2 flag in compilation, checked. It seems that i have to aviod writing avx2 intrinsic code, which need -mavx2 flag

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to specifying the `-mavx2` flag generally would be to use function attributes specifying `avx2` just on the relevant functions.

```c
void __attribute__ ((__target__ ("avx2"))) function_with_avx2(...) {
  ...
}

void function_without_avx2(...) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's a solution. But a little inconvenience in organizing my code. At last, I decide to avoid avx2 intrinsic and replace all avx2 intrinsic with handwritten assembly code